# Python: Get all possible date format from a string and convert it into datetime object

Tags: regex, python-3.x, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have thousands of files that contains date string in their filename in any possible formats. Some examples are below

> 19022019_tasks.pdf
>
> Meeting_Minutes 12-19-18.pdf
>
> tasks_for-August-22-2018-Special-Meeting
>
> 27092018_minutes.pdf
>
> 02AUG2018-Meeting.pdf
>
> Minutes_meeting_08.02.2018.pdf
>
> file020719.pdf

and all other possible date format.

Currently am using regex for each date format to get it from filename and then converting it into datetime object using `datetime.strptime` method by providing relevant date format for each date string.

Issue is date format are countless. I can't write down all possible date format. **Am looking for some third party library or plugin that first get date string from filename and then convert it into python datetime object**.

Is there any such utility in python?

Comment: see https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/

Comment: @SebastienD its helping but its not working for format 12152018 OR 121518

Comment: you'll have to tweak it a little bit with date_format attribute

Comment: What I did the last time I encountered this problem was make a list of `datetime` format strings corresponding to all the possible date formats, and then just loop through them until I found one that worked

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
import dateparser
import calendar 
import re

month_full = [x.lower() for x in list(calendar.month_name)]  # ['january', 'february',... ]
month_short = [x.lower() for x in list(calendar.month_abbr)] # ['jan', 'feb',... ]

def parseDate(date_str):

    #see if month is written in the filename
    for idx, x in enumerate(month_full):
        if idx == 0: continue
        if x in date_str:
            date_str = date_str.lower().replace(x, str(idx).zfill(2) )

    for idx, x in enumerate(month_short):
        if idx == 0: continue
        if x in date_str:
            date_str = date_str.lower().replace(x, str(idx).zfill(2) )


    date_str = date_str.replace('-', '').replace('.', '')

    #Extract digits with len > 6 and < 9 in string
    date_str= [x for x in re.findall(r'([0-9]{6,8})', date_str)][0]

    #Possible dateformats
    date_formats = {6:['%d%M%y','%m%d%y' ], 8:['%d%m%Y', '%m%d%Y']}

    try:
        #Filter out results where date was parsed with minutes
        return list(set([dateparser.parse(date_str, date_formats=[x]) for x in date_formats[len(date_str)] if dateparser.parse(date_str, date_formats=[x]).minute == 0] ))

    except:
        return dateparser.parse(date_str)

dates = ["19022019_tasks.pdf","Meeting_Minutes 12-19-18.pdf", "tasks_for-August-22-2018-Special-Meeting","27092018_minutes.pdf","02AUG2018-Meeting.pdf","Minutes_meeting_08.02.2018.pdf","file020719.pdf"]

for x in dates:
    print(x)
    print('===>', parseDate(x))
    print()
```

output:

```
19022019_tasks.pdf
===> [datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 19, 0, 0)]

Meeting_Minutes 12-19-18.pdf
===> [datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 19, 0, 0)]

tasks_for-August-22-2018-Special-Meeting
===> [datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 22, 0, 0)]

27092018_minutes.pdf
===> [datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 27, 0, 0)]

02AUG2018-Meeting.pdf
===> [datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 2, 0, 0)]

Minutes_meeting_08.02.2018.pdf
===> [datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 2, 0, 0)]

file020719.pdf
===> [datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 7, 0, 0)]
```

Note that in some cases you'll have to decide which one corresponds (for ex. 08.02.2018 could be either February 8th or August 2nd)